# How to update itertools cartesian product

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, python-itertools

the aim of this question is to optimize a search procedure. The search space is obtained through the cartesian product of a set of vectors, obtained by `itertools. product`, that correspond to finite variable domains. When a feasible solution is found I would like to retrieve its 'information' in order to discard other worse solutions. This means constraining the cartesian product obtained by `itertools. product`
Let's suppose that the following code:

`flightCombinations = product(*flightRanges.values())`

returns the following matrix,  with delay values:

[image: set of solutions]

`flightRanges` consists of a dictionary whose values are a list of delays [[60, 660, 720], [0, 60, 180, 600], [-1, 0, 60]...]. The value -1 is a cancellation. The objective of the search procedure is to minimize cancellations and the amount of delay(s).

The algorithm loops through `flightCombinations`  according to:

```
for combo in flightCombinations:
    solutionValue = findSolution(combo)
    #optimize(flightCombinations, solutionValue)
```

The best solution is the first row since it is the one with the least amount of delay, 60 in total respectively. It is of no use to continue to loop through the remaining rows. I would like to remove the remaining solutions from `flightCombinations`  using a method such as the one commented:

`optimize(flightCombinations, solutionValue)`

Is it possible to update the cartesian product in `flightCombinations`  ? Is it possible to remove rows according to a criteria same as numpy array?

Comment: How do you know you have found the optimal solution ? You can simply check for that condition and break if you have met it.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me the connection between the table above the the flightRange.values() that you mention.  Could you clarify?  But also. . .  itertools.product() itself doesn't allow any shortcutting; it is a generator that wants to show you everyhing.  But you can look at its source code and see if it can be adapted to your purposes.